# Не получается спарсить <td>

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

С помощью `BeautifulSoup` пытаюсь парсить страницу `html`:

```
bpoint = soup.find('td', text='tкип').find_next_sibling("td")
bpoint_ex = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", bpoint)
```

Необходимо получить соответственно температуру кипения из справочника, сам `html` выглядит так:

```
<tr>
  <td>t<sub>кип.</sub></td>
  <td>1413 °C</td>
</tr>
```

Не получается по вот такой причине:

> bpoint = soup.find('td', text='tкип').find_next_sibling("td")
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'

UPD Однако по такой схеме работает другая характеристика:

```
molar = soup.find('td', text='Молярная масса').find_next_sibling('td')
molar_ex = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", str(molar))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел аналогичный способ, который приводит к желаемому результату:

```
# Melting point
mpoint = soup.find_all('td')[1]
```